AWS Lightsail bitnami bncert tool certificate location?
I am using AWS Lightsail and generated some tls certificates. Where does the bncert tool place the certificates at? I need to add it to my express app configuration.
Adding "/opt/bitnami/apache/conf/bitnami/certs/server.key" Just gives me a wrong certificate from example.com
